# Preventing Dismiss of Ios Alert even when clicked on positive button or any button

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying to create an alert on xamarin ios native,
the alert would be have only one button.
current when I click on  button the alert get auto dismissed and also fire the event of button clicked.
I am looking for a solution where the alert should not dismiss on clicking any button and should stay

```
        var okCancelAlertController = UIAlertController.Create(title, message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

        //Add Actions

        if (cancel != null)
        {
            okCancelAlertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create(cancel, UIAlertActionStyle.Default, alert =>
            {
              
            }));
        }

        okCancelAlertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create(accept, UIAlertActionStyle.Default, alert =>
        {
            

        }));

        //Present Alert
        var rootVC = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows[0].RootViewController;
        rootVC.PresentViewController(okCancelAlertController, true, null);
    }
```

this is code I have implemented yet

Comment: If it stays, then it isn't an alert. Explain how this would be used.

Answer (score 0):

This is a system behaviour. When you click on button alert closes and you can't prevent this.

An workaround is to add an LongPressGesture which intercepts the default action's handler. Consider the following code:

```
var okCancelAlertController = UIAlertController.Create(title, message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

//create action
UIAlertAction cancel = UIAlertAction.Create("Cancel", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, alert => Console.WriteLine("Cancel was clicked"));
UIAlertAction accept = UIAlertAction.Create("Accept", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, alert => Console.WriteLine("Accept was clicked"));

//add action
okCancelAlertController.AddAction(cancel);
okCancelAlertController.AddAction(accept);

var rootVC = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows[0].RootViewController;
rootVC.PresentViewController(okCancelAlertController, true, ()=>
{
    // this is based on the UIAlertController's hierarchy
    UIStackView stackView = okCancelAlertController.View.Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Subviews[1].Subviews[2].Subviews[0].Subviews[0] as UIStackView;
    // this view contains accept action handler. add longpress gesture to intercept the action handler. 
    UIView myView = stackView.ArrangedSubviews[2];
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer longGesture = new UILongPressGestureRecognizer((gesture) =>
    {
        if (gesture.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began)
        {
            accept.Enabled = false;
        }
        else if (gesture.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended)
        {
            accept.Enabled = true;
        }
    });
    longGesture.MinimumPressDuration = 0;
    myView.AddGestureRecognizer(longGesture);
});
```

The view containing cancel action is also in stackView.ArrangedSubviews collection. You may have a try.

Hope it works